# Woocommerce, Billing Country and State in Checkout page are not changing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

It has been fixed to one specific country and it’s not showing a drop-down option to use on the checkout page to select different country. I not using cache, or any  kind of minified CSS or html

Comment: What does mean *"I don’t know why it has been fixed to one specific country"*. Your question is unclear, please edit it to provide more details…

Answer (score 0):

In Woocommerce Settings, under General, check what is set in
*Selling location(s)* and *Shipping location(s)*

Comment: its is set to "Ship to all countries" that not a problem, actually if i go back to Wordpress default theme, then the drop down is working and when i toggle to my theme in wordpress it aint working

Comment: Does it show some errors in Browser's Debug Console?

Comment: Yes i did but haven't found anything concerning, i though maybe the plugin would be interfering so i almost deactivated all the plugin but still problem remain same. Actually i tried to insert the dropdown code in function.php given her - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-the-default-state-and-country-on-the-checkout/

but it broke my website, so i used code snippet but that also didnt work

Comment: Try to switch the Theme to Storefront or one of the WordPress default themes.